# NVD3 converting JSON Data

Tags: nvd3.js

I have json data in the following format :

```
       [{ 
          "label" : "A Label" ,
          "value" : -29.765957771107
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "B Label" , 
          "value" : 0
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "C Label" , 
          "value" : 32.807804682612
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "D Label" , 
          "value" : 196.45946739256
        }]
```

**I want to create a bar chart in NVD3** where x coordinates will be label and the y coordinates will be the value. So how can I achieve it. I have gone through many examples where the JSON data was used is a different format but my data is as shown above.

**EDITED CODE:**

Here is the js code through which I am trying to create a chart in NVD3 .

```
d3.json("http://localhost:8080/api/study", function(data) {
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart().x(function(d) {
            return d.label;
        }).y(function(d) {
            return d.value;
        }).margin({
            top : 30,
            right : 20,
            bottom : 50,
            left : 175
        }).showValues(true)//Show bar value next to each bar.
        .tooltips(true)//Show tooltips on hover.
        //.transitionDuration(350)
        .showControls(true);
        //Allow user to switch between "Grouped" and "Stacked" mode.

        chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

        d3.select('#chart11 svg').datum(data).call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Most charts in nvd3.js have the following data sceleton:

```
[
 {
    key: "<Series name>",
    color: "<CSS color>",
    values: [
        {x: 0, y: 10},
        {x: 1, y: 20},
        {x: 2, y: 30}
        ....
    ]
 },
 {
    key: "<Series name>"
    ...
 }
]
```

In your case the following format will be valid:

```
[
 {
   key: "Series 1", 
   values:  [
    { 
      "label" : "A Label" ,
      "value" : -29.765957771107
    } , 
    { 
      "label" : "B Label" , 
      "value" : 0
    } , 
    { 
      "label" : "C Label" , 
      "value" : 32.807804682612
    } , 
    { 
      "label" : "D Label" , 
      "value" : 196.45946739256
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

You will need to specify axis properties accessors:

```
var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
  .x(function(d) { return d.label })
  .y(function(d) { return d.value })
```

Comment: Well, you can simply convert your coming data to the appropriate format. Don't see any problems with that. Can you put a link to your code so I can understand what exactly is causing the problem?

Comment: Hi, since the data is coming from the client API so cannot share the link but I have edited my question where I have added my js code. Kindly look at that. My data is coming from an API and the format I have shown above.

Comment: So you need to transform your data to the required format inside callback which is passed to d3.json.  I've created a complete example for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9o0r3oen/1/)